# JavaScript function that injects new HTML <li> into the HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a JavaScript function that allows me with a click to save the last element of an array (standbyWord array) and then have that saved element appear as an HTML `<li>`.

I have managed to change the `innerHTML`, so each time the save button is clicked the last element from the standbyWord array is saved in the savedWords array. However, I would like that each time the save button is pushed a new `<li>` appears with that new saved word.

```
<div>
  <ul>
     <li id="listWord"></li>
  </ul>
</div>

let savedWords = [];

function saveWord(){
      savedWords.push(standbyWord[standbyWord.length - 1]);
      document.getElementById('savedWordCount').innerHTML = savedWords.length;
      document.getElementById('listWord').innerHTML = savedWords;
    }
```

Comment: have you tried the appendChild() method on html elements? [appendChild()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp#:~:text=The%20appendChild()%20method%20appends,the%20paragraph%20to%20the%20document.)
Also, your example code is incomplete, please insert full examples with save button and standbyWord variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use innerHTML, you need to be aware that this will replace the entire inner contents of the tag - as your code stands, you will just end up with a string of words BUT, if you want them to be within `li` tags, you would have `li` tags within an `li` whereas they should be within a `ul` or `ol` tag .  If you change your `ul` element to have the `id="listword"` and remove the `li` tag, you can do:

```js
let savedwords = ["cat","dog", "rabbit", "horse", "donkey", "whale", "mouse"];

let lw = document.getElementById("listword");
lw.innerHTML = "<li>" + savedwords.join("</li><li>") + "</li>";
```

```html
<div>
  <ul id="listword">
  
  
  </ul>

</div>
```

Or, you could do as @JustAMicrobe suggests and create a new `li` object for just the new word and append that to the ul object using `appendChild`.